# What are the latest Released Ruby gems which are very helpful

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want to know what are the latest released ruby gems which everyone should know and try to implement it in real application.I have gone through the ruby gem site but there i can't find any.So please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a vast amount of resources to get updates on the latest ruby and rubygems news, here's some:

- **[RubyWeekly](https://rubyweekly.com/)**

  > A free, once–weekly e-mail round-up of Ruby news and articles.
- **[Changelog Nightly](https://changelog.com/nightly)**

  Changelog Nightly will send you an email every night (10pm US
  Central) with the latest and starred GitHub repositories. Also, they have a great podcast on different topics.
- **[GitHub Discover](https://github.com/dashboard/discover)**

  You could also use Github's discover tab to browse repositories.